# Spring Security : OAuth invalid grant

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

We need to implement a customized OAuth2 solution, where the UI client reaches the resource server through a proxy. UI calls the endpoints of the proxy, and the proxy executes the authentication with the OAuth2 server. If this process is successful, it calls further the resource server, and forwards its response.

During login, the /security/login is called by the UI and this calls the OAuth server's authorize endpoint with response_type, scope, redirect_uri, and client_id. This call gives back a loginpage to the user, the login is successful through this.

After this, the redirect is executed with the authorization_code. Then the OAuth2/token endpoint is called with the received code.

The problem is:

At the above described last point, the Authorization Code which has been issued by the auth server is not accepted by the same server. Error: invalid_grant

We could not get accepted the code which was received few seconds earlier by Postman either, and we do not know why,  in addition, in the error_description there's no data.

We don't have any debug console log detail, anything.
What should we try?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the client written with (server-side redering client like JSP, PHP, etc. or client-side rendering like Angular, React, Vue, Flutter, Android / iOS native) ?

Comment: Now we just try with postman, to create a flow, through the component elements (ie. proxy, etc.) So no client yet (Angular will be if the flow is working, and we'll try with that too)

Answer (score 0):

If using Postman and "rich" clients Angular, React, Flutter, Vue, Android, iOS, etc.), why not authenticate against authorization-server with Postman as OAuth2 client (authentication tab) and later with Angular (with [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client))?

In this configuration, you configure

- API(s) as normal OAuth2 [resource-server(s)](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials)
- clients as ... OAuth2 clients
- gateway being mostly a single transparent point of contact, just forwarding Authorization header (request to secured endpoints should already have a Bearer access-token)

Optionally gateway could be configured as a resource server to enforce some security rules before forwarding a request, but I wouldn't advise it as resource-servers are in a much better position to do that: it has access to resources (frequently, authorization depends on both the user and the resource being accessed) and is the place where business logic is and unit-tested (aren't your access restrictions specified by the business?)